# Shifting Values in R

Tags: r

I have a data set called dt. A snapshot of it is given below:

```
   GVKEY FYEAR      ROANew
1   1004  2003  0.00502037
2   1004  2004  0.02143984
3   1004  2005  0.04110110
4   1004  2006  0.05732849
5   1004  2007  0.06185600
6   1004  2008  0.05741953
7   1004  2009  0.03100725
8   1004  2010  0.04357631
9   1004  2011  0.03473527
10  1004  2012  0.02538919
11  1013  2003 -0.06284052
12  1013  2004  0.01203670
13  1013  2005  0.07471904
14  1013  2006  0.04176201
15  1013  2007  0.06297020...
```

I want to create a new column ROAL, where for each GVKEY, ROAL(t) = ROANew (t-1). Thus, the new data would look like:

```
   GVKEY FYEAR      ROANew        ROAL
1   1004  2003  0.00502037          NA
2   1004  2004  0.02143984  0.00502037
3   1004  2005  0.04110110  0.02143984
4   1004  2006  0.05732849  0.04110110
5   1004  2007  0.06185600  0.05732849
6   1004  2008  0.05741953  0.06185600
7   1004  2009  0.03100725  0.05741953
8   1004  2010  0.04357631  0.03100725
9   1004  2011  0.03473527  0.04357631
10  1004  2012  0.02538919  0.03473527
11  1013  2003 -0.06284052          NA
12  1013  2004  0.01203670 -0.06284052
13  1013  2005  0.07471904  0.01203670
14  1013  2006  0.04176201  0.07471904
15  1013  2007  0.06297020  0.04176201...
```

I did it in two ways :

```
dt$ROAL <- ave(dt$ROANew, data$GVKEY, FUN = function(x) {c(NA, head(x,-1))});
```

but, I get a warning message

```
 Warning messages:
1: In split.default(x, g) :
  data length is not a multiple of split variable
2: In split.default(seq_along(x), f, drop = drop, ...) :
  data length is not a multiple of split variable
```

The second code is,

```
dt <- ddply(dt,.(GVKEY),function(x) {x$ROAL <- c(NA, head(x$ROANew, -1));x});
```

But this is one is very slow. Any alternative and efficient way to do this one?

Edit:
Just realized that there was a typo in the first code: data instead of dt at one place. Would still won't delete this post, in case, might help someone. And still, one can help me answering, whether there is an more efficient way to do the task over

```
dt$ROAL <- ave(dt$ROANew, data$GVKEY, FUN = function(x) {c(NA, head(x,-1))});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ave` is the way to go here. In case you have a big data set , you can move to the `data.table` wich is also more syntax sugar:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(dt)
DT[, ROAL :=c(NA,head(ROANew,-1)),by='GVKEY']
```